# How to use Clion to debug existing executable w/o configuring and building the project?

Tags: clion

I have an executable built from the source code using `./configure && make`.

I need to debug (using gdb) the executable in Clion.

I opened the project directory in Clion and created the debug configuration containing:

- executable name
- program arguments
- working directory

After I press `Run -> Debug` the following error appears:

```
Pre-configuration commands finished with code: 1
```

As I understand, Clion is trying to configure the project. Is that correct?

Instead of showing this error I need Clion to run gdb for the debug configuration. How to do that?